# JOGL in Eclipse for Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, jogl

Im trying to get JOGL to work in Eclipse on my Mac but im having some issues; just to clarify I have never used JOGL before in my entire life so this whole thing is very new to me. Ive tried looking for some tutorials but they are all outdated/use different files on every website I go to.

So, I have downloaded the latest build from the JOGL site (jogamp-all-platforms.7z) and I have extracted it. I have a new project in Eclipse which I have just created, when I select 'Add JARs...' in User Libraries im only given the choice of '.classpath' or '.project' which doesn't seem to be an issue on any of the tutorials written. I was just wondering if im doing something wrong at this point?

Answer (score 0):

It's explained
[here](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE#Eclipse_IDE_project) in the official JogAmp wiki.